# How to subset a set of variables and use Aggregate function in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and i'm working on a automation,i have a list of variables in a separate file based on which the values needs to be aggregated in the master dataset.The Master datastructure is attached [Master Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTkG5.png)
and the referal dataset contains the vars to be aggregated [Referal dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELsiG.png)
Of the 6 variables i need to aggregate the Variables D,E,F by Sum(C)(as per the referal dataset).

The below code does my requirement manually,

```
X<-aggregate(C,by=list(D,E,F),FUN=sum)
```

But i need a code which does the same funtionality automatically.I tried making loops but the problem i face is that both datasets dont have same data.frame size. Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Better to include your example data rather than a picture of it. Guidance over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like you want to do a few things:
1) read in the master/referent datasets
2) subset the master according to the values in the referent
3) compute column sums on the master?

also, is there a specific reason you want to use aggregate()? there are probably lots of ways to do this. In any case, here is what i would do:

```
# assuming master is a dataframe or matrix, referent is a vector
# just simulating them here because not clear how you are reading them in
master = matrix(rnorm(36),6)
colnames(master) = c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
referent = c('D','E','F')
colSums(master[,referent])
```

so is that doing what you want to do? I like colSums because it's a handy built-in. I am not an R superstar though so it is possible that other ways are better for some reason.

Comment: Subsetting the values is where i face the problem , Since my dataset is very large and i could not feed all values from refferal datasets manually, The aggregate() function provides me the sum of values for each attributes based on Variable C. And i need to make a generalized code (i,e) I should not select variables by their names,they should fall in loop once i mention the dataset name.:)